# Firestore rule to only add/remove one item of array

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

To optimize usage, I have a Firestore collection with only one document, consisting in a single field, which is an array of strings.

This is what the data looks like in the collection. Just one document with one field, which is an array:
[image]

On the client side, the app is simply retrieving the entire `status` document, picking one at random, and then sending the entire array back minus the one it picked

```
var all = await metaRef.doc("status").get();
List tokens=all['all'];
var r=new Random();
int numar=r.nextInt(tokens.length);
var ales=tokens[numar];
tokens.removeAt(numar);
metaRef.doc("status").set({"all":tokens});
```

Then it tries to do some stuff with the string, which may fail or succeed. If it succeeds, then no more writing to the database, but if it fails it fetches that array again, adds the string back and pushes it:

```
var all = await metaRef.doc("status").get();
List tokens=all['all'];
List<String> toate=(tokens.map((element) => element as String).toList());
toate.add(ales.toString());
metaRef.doc("status").set({"all":toate});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods associated with the [Set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Set) object.

Here is an example to check that only 1 item was removed:

```
allow update: if checkremoveonlyoneitem()

function checkremoveonlyoneitem() {
  let set = resource.data.array.toSet();
  let setafter = request.resource.data.array.toSet();
  return set.size() == setafter.size() + 1
    && set.intersection(setafter).size() == 1;
}
```

Then you can check that only one item was added. And you should also add additional checks in case the array does not exist on your doc.

Comment: thanks for this. I'll implement a bit later on and leave feedback

Comment: So it's getting denied. Does any of the code in the function depend on what I named the fields? Like should the array be named `array` ?Is there any other customization I should implement to have this work please?

Comment: Please show 1) your client side code and 2) a screenshot of some example data

Comment: Added both up top. Thanks. One thing I should mention is this works fine with the general rule (allow read, write: if true)

Comment: Which update is failing? The first or second one? Can you print to the console `tokens` just after line 2 and `tokens` or `toate` just before the last line? Can you also show all the values in Firestore?

Comment: the first one is failing, but I'm also testing it with `rules playground` and doesn't allow writing anything

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about how the app performs the task i.e., successfully or not, then I guess it is nice idea to implement this logic in the client code. You can just make a simple conditional block which deletes the field from the document if the operation succeeds, either due to offline condition or any other issue. You can find the following sample from the [following document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) regarding how to do it. Like this, with just one write you can delete the field which the user picks without updating the whole document.

```
city_ref = db.collection(u'cities').document(u'BJ')
city_ref.update({
    u'capital': firestore.DELETE_FIELD
})snippets.py
```

Comment: that would work, except I need that string removed while the client tries to use it, so that nobody else can pick it.

Comment: For that you can have snapshot listener which works in real time. You can change the above logic slightly and delete the string whenever someone picks the string from a document. If it doesn't succeed, then you can add it back with a single write using set method.

Comment: Can you please let me know if the above comment helps you?